# MySQL join query only one row with reference table

Tags: mysql

Here is my 5 tables.

**product**

- id(PK)
- name

**description**

- id(PK)
- body

**price**

- id(PK)
- currency

**product_description**

- id(PK)
- product_id
- description_id

**product_price**

- id(PK)
- product_id
- price_id

Table `product`, `description`, `price` is where stored actual data.

And table `product_description` and `product_price` is reference table.

My expected query result like this.

`product_id | product_name | description_body | price_currency`

**Current table's data**

```
product
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | first product  |
|  2 | second product |
|  3 | third product  |
+----+----------------+
```

```
description
+----+------------+
| id | body       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | first desc |
|  2 | second des |
|  3 | third desc |
+----+------------+
```

```
price
+----+-------------+
| id | currency    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | first cur   |
|  2 | second cur2 |
|  3 | third cur   |
+----+-------------+
```

```
product_description
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | product_id | description_id |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |          1 |              1 |
|  2 |          2 |              2 |
|  3 |          3 |              3 |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

```
product_price
+----+------------+----------+
| id | product_id | price_id |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        1 |
|  2 |          2 |        2 |
|  3 |          3 |        3 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT product.*, description.body, price.currency FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_description ON product.id = product_description.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_price ON product.id = product_price.product_id
LEFT JOIN description ON description.id = product_description.description_id
LEFT JOIN price ON price.id = product_price.price_id
```

**Result**

```
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name           | body       | currency    |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | first product  | first desc | first cur   |
|  2 | second product | second desc| second cur2 |
|  3 | third product  | third desc | third cur   |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

In that moment, If I insert into `product_description` one more row that has `product_id=1` and re querying, it shows many rows that `product_id=2`.

After insert into `product_description` values(4, 2, 1)

```
product_description
+----+------------+----------------+
| id | product_id | description_id |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  1 |          1 |              1 |
|  2 |          2 |              2 |
|  3 |          3 |              3 |
|  4 |          2 |              1 |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

After join query.

```
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
| id | name           | body       | currency    |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | first product  | first desc | first cur   |
|  2 | second product | second desc | second cur2 |
|  2 | second product | first desc | second cur2 |
|  3 | third product  | third desc | third cur   |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+
```

You know that because of `product=2` row's count is 2 in `product_description`, result print all of it.

But I want to only last one rows that contain `product=2`.

Maybe limit or distinct is useful, I don't know it is possible.

Can I use limit or distinct in join query?

Comment: You will get more complex problems with this schema as soon as you add more rows in other tables for the same product.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That's right. So I tried to move all of mysql data to mongodb right now. Above post is related to migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
    SELECT product.*, description.body, price.currency FROM product
    LEFT JOIN 
    ( select * from product_description
      where product_description.id in (select max(id) from product_description b 
      where product_description.product_id=b.product_id)
    ) as x ON product.id = x.product_id
    LEFT JOIN product_price ON product.id = product_price.product_id
    LEFT JOIN description ON description.id = x.description_id
    LEFT JOIN price ON price.id = product_price.price_id
```

Comment: In your code, If `product_id=5`(or any other number) is exist in only `product` table(do not exist in `product_description` and `product_price`), doesn't show in query result.

Comment: I have to print all of `product` even though that hasn't any related data.